# no Login possible anymore after several updates

Tags: upgrade, login, cuda, console

After installing the lastest  Nvidia Cuda Package, and several other system updates (seems an Ubuntu 16.04.03 upgrade also) I only get to the headaching login loop.

Tried quite a lot, nothing helps. Cant install `fglrx` (for the Package exists no Installation candidate), `purged Nvidia`, re-installed [runfile-pkg] it, got the `4.4.0`Kernel, gcc version `5.4.0` and lots of other help from Existing solutions. Nothing 
After install and choose `lxdm`, I just reboot into `tty1` instead login loop. Couldnt login as new root after changing password.

Read about gui-updates and auto-remove commands could be causing this as well, which I both did from time to time as well.

What else can I try to get back? Please help, I m tearing my hair out soon

---

edit:

After CTRL+ALT+F3 shell login

```
$ ls -lah
```

and

```
$ chown username:username .Xauthority
```

I can login as root (at least). Still I dont know how to access my normal account...

Comment: Are you coming back to login screen after entering with your password? If yes, then it is related to login loop.

Comment: So just to let you know: I tried for almost 24h, I tried all login-loop tutorials, first tried the high-voted recomments, then the less voted. I tried everything(!), that a noob can try.... NOTHING. I m little sad, cuz nobody seemed be interested to help me either. De nada. So my solution finally was BUY A NEW DRIVE and REINSTALL UBUNTU 16.04 completely. :/